# How to place labels at set coordinates using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to manually set the coordinates of the `geom_label` in ggplot. The problem is that my plot is a circle (not centred at zero)...and Im trying to figure out a way to 'expand' the x & y positions of the labels, so they are pushed out... hopefully the example below will explain what I mean.

Aside: There is a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580024/position-geom-label-on-the-outside-of-a-network-using-ggplot)... which does work... but Im not exactly sure what is happening in the code for that answer. I was hoping to find a relatively simple solution. Here's my problem.

If I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(5.000000e-01, 8.090170e-01, 1.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00, 8.090170e-01,
        5.000000e-01, 1.909830e-01, 5.836788e-17, 0.000000e+00, 1.909830e-01),
  y = c(1.0000000, 0.9045085, 0.6545085, 0.3454915, 0.0954915, 
        0.0000000, 0.0954915, 0.3454915, 0.6545085, 0.9045085)
)

labels <- paste0("A", 1:10)
```

And use ggplot to plot:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(label = labels), nudge_y = 0.05) +
  theme_void()
p
```

This results in plotting a (almost) circle with the labels nudged slightly in the y-direction:[image: circle plot]

However, what I'm trying to achieve is the following (which I quickly made in photoshop):
[image: circle plot with moved labels]

In the second image, the labels have been moved to the outside of the points.

Here is my attempt at a solution (but it doesn't work). I was thinking I could take the coordinates of my point (i.e., x & y) and scale them between -1 and 1 like so:

```
LmatX <- (-1 - 1) * ((df$x - min(df$x)) / (max(df$x) - min(df$x))) +1
LmatY <- (-1 - 1) * ((df$y - min(df$y)) / (max(df$y) - min(df$y))) +1
```

Then, if any of the values in `LmatX` are positive, then I add some value... and if the values of `LmatX` are negative, I could subtract by the same value. Similarly for `LmatY`. For example,

```
LmatX <- ifelse(LmatX > 0, LmatX + 1, LmatX - 1)
LmatY <- ifelse(LmatY > 0, LmatY + 1, LmatY - 1)
```

However, the above code is wrong... because, at the moment, the zero vales in `LmatX` and `LmatY` are being subtracted by one (whereas they should remain zero!).
My idea was I could use the values obtained by `LmatX` and `LmatY` and multiply (or add... not sure which) to my original `df$x` and `df$y` to create a new set of coordinates to place the labels.

Any suggestion as to how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this problem. Following on from the method I laid out in the question... I first scale between -1 & 1 (I was scaling incorrectly in the question)

```
LmatX <- (1 - -1) * ((df$x - min(df$x)) / (max(df$x) - min(df$x))) + -1
LmatY <- (1 - -1) * ((df$y - min(df$y)) / (max(df$y) - min(df$y))) + -1
```

Then I used a nested `ifelse` to add or subtract a small value depending if the values of `LmatX` or `LmatY` were positive or negative:

```
newX <- ifelse(LmatX > 0, df$x + 0.05, ifelse(LmatX < 0, df$x - 0.05, df$x))
newY <- ifelse(LmatY > 0, df$y + 0.05, ifelse(LmatY < 0, df$y - 0.05, df$y))
```

Then I created a new data frame with the coordinates of the labels:

```
df_2 <- data.frame(newX, newY)
```

and plot using the new df in `geom_label`:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(data =  df_2, aes(x = newX, y = newY, label = labels)) +
  theme_void()
p
```

Which results in:
[image]